# Will my bike hitch fit on any car?

Tags: transportation, transport-by-car

I'm trying to sell a 4-bike hitch on craigslist.   One thing I'm unsure of is whether or not it's tailored to universally fit on all cars.  I'm worried because if it's too specific, a few people who own those cars will buy it, but if it's universal, it should be okay.

What is the standard for hitches? Are they universal? Or are they custom fitted to support different vehicles?

Comment: Does this belong on auto, instead of bicycle?  I'm unsure where to put this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for the vehicle most buyers need only consider the size of hitch they have, 1 1/4" or 2" are the typical sizes and try to get a hitch of the same size. You can usually get an adapter to fit a rack that is sized differently than the hitch.

Typically the hitch racks sit a bit back off the rear of your car to accommodate rear features of most vehicles. I'd only be worried if they had a spare tire mounted on the rear of the vehicle.

Comment: It's easy to get an adapter so a 2" hitch receiver (car side) takes a 1 1/4" hitch carrier, however the other way round means the carrier needs to sit further out from the car - not ideal but still can be done.

Comment: In my country we have 50mm and 1 7/8" towballs, both are "standard" but the smaller imperial size is most common.